# How do you bind a viewmodel subclass values in an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Two `ViewModels`

```
CreateEventViewModel
CreateAccountViewModel
```

`CreateEventViewModel` looks like this

```
public class CreateEventViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CreateAccountViewModel CreateAccountViewModel;
}
```

And in the view I can use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateAccountViewModel.Email)
```

All is great so far, but how am I to bind the value to `CreateAccountViewModel.Email`?

The binding to `CreateEventViewModel.Name` works great with this setup

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name")] CreateEventViewModel eventViewModel){
    ...
}
```

But how would i write to get the binding towards `CreateEventViewModel.CreateAccountViewModel.Email`?

Comment: You need to remove the `BindAttribute` - its specifies that you only bind the `Name` property and exclude all other properties. And since you using view models, a `BindAttribute` should never be used - that's one of the benefits of using view models.

Comment: Note also that `CreateAccountViewModel` is a field in your model, not a property, so it would never be bound correctly anyway (add `{ get; set; }`)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should mention get set

```
public virtual CreateAccountViewModel CreateAccountView {get; set;}
```

now Email property in CreateAccountViewModel should be accessible inside your create method

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateEventViewModel eventViewModel){
    var email = eventViewModel.CreateAccountView.Email;
}
```

**When we pass Model object as a parameter ASP.net MVC automatically does model binding for you,
ASP.NET MVC Model all the data coming from HTTP world and use the DefaultModelBinder class which magically does all the type conversion and mapping of all these values to the Model properties.**

In the Create action we are already using model binding. But to make binding work your html input tags attribute id and name should be same as model properties.
ex: `<input class="textbox" id="Name" name="Name" type"text">` and for `CreateAccountViewModel` inside `CreateEventViewModel` do use ModelObject.PropertyName as in input tag below

```
<input class="textbox" id="CreateAccountView.Email" name="CreateAccountView.Email" type"text">
```

Comment: This works, yes. But how would use solve it using bindings?

Comment: you are already using binding because you are passing CreateEventViewModel object as parameter

Comment: But lets say that CreateAccountView has Name, which i wouldnt allowed to bet set in this action. Binding it to only CreateAccountView.Email would not allow CreateAccountView.Name to be set in the action?

Comment: Hey @MarcusBrunsten: This is how you bind: ```[Bind("Name,CreateAccountView")]```. However, this binds every field in CreateAccountView, not just Email.  Still not sure how to specify just Email, but if you didn't want name: ```[Bind("CreateAccountView")]```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to bind the Email field of a member class (CreateAccountViewModel) to an action.  You just need to pass the member class to the action;

```
public ActionResult Create(
[Bind(Include = "Name")] 
     CreateEventViewModel eventViewModel,
[Bind(Include = "Email")] 
     CreateAccountViewModel accountViewModel){
    ...
}
```

as an aside, this also works although you can't exclude other properties of the member class such as say, Email2.  By the way, in this example I have renamed the field name to accountViewModel since using CreateAccountViewModel creates ambiguities

```
public ActionResult Create(
[Bind(Include = "Name,accountViewModel")] 
     CreateEventViewModel eventViewModel){
    ...
}
```